# MVC 3 - _Layout.cshtml. Add a logo to the site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MVC 3, I'm trying to add an Image to the _Layout.cshtml file.
I tried

```
<img runat="server" id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="Content/Images/mailworks.png" />
```

no success. The logo only appear on some views. on others views for some reason the image is supposed to be in some other location - found it using firebug.

Comment: try <img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/mailworks.png")" />

Comment: runat="server" - not needed in MVC

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/mailworks.png")" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/mailworks.png")"...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another quick solution : just append '/' at the beginning of the src's path.